# How to use GraphView library to draw with stringbuilder value?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have a fragment (`Fragment2`) that receives temperature value from other devices with Bluetooth. I want to draw real time graph of temperature vs  time.

Temperature values are stored in form of StringBuilder. Ex-:

```
{temp[0]=20, temp[1]=30,temp[2]=34,...
```

The temperature value has to be StringBuilder. However, draw graph method requires double values like:

```
private void addEntry() {
         series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastX++, RANDOM.nextDouble() * 10d), true, 10);
       }
```

y value has to be double. How should I solve this problem?

My codes:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    private View convertView;

    TextView incomingMessages;
    StringBuilder messages;
    StringBuilder [] temp = new StringBuilder[1000];
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    int LastPointX=0;
     int lasty;
     int x=0;
     int count=1000;

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
    int index=0;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);
            incomingMessages= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            messages =new StringBuilder();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("incomingMessage"));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String text=intent.getStringExtra("theMessage");
            messages.append(text+"\n");
            incomingMessages.setText(messages);
            temp[index]= new StringBuilder(messages);
            Log.d("deneme", "message:"+messages+"\n"+"temp"+temp[index]);
            index++;

            messages.delete(0, messages.length());
            Log.d("temp0",temp[0]+"temp1"+temp[1]+"\n"+"temp2"+temp[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp[index]= new StringBuilder(messages);`, why is this saved as StringBuilder array and not as double array? Can you give an example `message`?

Comment: because message value Stringbuilder. Message comming for example 34 my app show this number and message value equal to temp[i] value so i save message value at temperature value.

Comment: if i change to double i dont use this code:messages.append(text+"\n");
            incomingMessages.setText(messages);
            temp[index]= new StringBuilder(messages);

Comment: You can convert double to a string and append it to message. Ex- `String valueString = 12.32 + "" // => "12.32"`

Comment: So, how can i draw temp[0],temp[1] value it will be double, how can i getting and draw with temp[i] values ?

Comment: I tried with this type but i have error null object